# Find solutions near $I$ of $P^2=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The questions is:

> Using the exponential, find all solutions near $I$ of the equation $P^2=I$.

I did some try with the exponential:

$$e^A=I+\frac{A}{1!}+\frac{A^2}{2!}+\cdots$$

$e^A=I$ while $A=0$, and let $P=e^X$, as $e^A=P^2$, $X=\frac{A}{2}$, which is also $0$.

Then, how can I get the solutions?

Comment: What's meant by near $I$?  For $2\times 2$, $P=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ \frac{1-a^2}{b} & -a \end{pmatrix}$ which is unlikely to be close to $I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential map $\varphi(X) = e^X$ is a diffeomorphism around $X = 0$. Thus we can find $r_1 > 0$ such that $\varphi|_{B(0,r_1)}$ is a diffeomorphism. Choose $r_2 > 0$ such that $B(e^0,r_2) = B(I,r_2) \subseteq \varphi(B(0,\frac{r_1}{2}))$. Thus, we get that if $||P - I|| < r_2$ then there exists a **unique** $X$ with $||X|| < \frac{r_1}{2}$ and $e^X = P$.

Let $P$ satisfy $P^2 = I$ and $||P - I|| < r_2$ and let $X$ be the unique $X$ such that $e^X = P$ and $||X|| < \frac{r_1}{2}$. Then

$$ P^2 = (e^{X})^2 = e^{2X} = I = e^{0}. $$

But now $||2X|| < r_1$ and since $\varphi|_{B(0,r_1)}$ is a diffeomorphism, we get $2X = 0$ so $X = 0$ and $P = I$. Thus, the only solution in $B(I,r_2)$ of the equation $P^2 = I$ is $P = I$.

Of course, this fact also follows from the fact that the map $X \mapsto X^2$ is a diffeomorphism near $X = I$.